# Vertically Align Center custom Radio box in <li>

Tags: html, css

I have a CSS styled Radio button that needs to show up inside of a `<UL><LI>`.  The prompt next to the Radio button itself is of variable length and size.

Any idea how I can get both the custom styled radio button as well as the prompt text to vertically align in the middle of the containing `<LI>`?

I would like to avoid absolute position where possible as the content for each item will vary. The only real requirement I have is that the `<DIV>` containing the prompt text remain a `<DIV>` item (as opposed to a `<SPAN>` or `<LABEL>`.

Code Pen here shows the issue: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/KgzjpX

```css
/* Unselected List Item */

ul li {
  display: block;
  border-bottom: 1px dotted lightgray;
}
/* hide Default radio element */

ul li input[type=radio] {
  visibility: hidden;
}
ul li label {
  display: inline-block;
  padding-left: 20px;
  z-index: 9;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.15s linear;
}
/* Outer circle, unselected, not-hovered */

ul li .check {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  border: 3px dotted purple;
  border-radius: 100%;
  height: 25px;
  width: 25px;
  z-index: 5;
  transition: border .25s linear;
  -webkit-transition: border .25s linear;
}
/* Outer circle, unselected, hovered */

ul li:hover .check {
  border: 3px solid green;
}
/* Inner circle */

ul li .check::before {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  content: '';
  border-radius: 100%;
  height: 15px;
  width: 15px;
  left: 5px;
  top: 5px;
  transition: background 0.1s linear;
  -webkit-transition: background 0.1s linear;
}
/* Outer circle, selected, unhovered */

input[type=radio]:checked ~ .check {
  border: 3px solid blue;
}
/* Inner circle, selected, unhovered */

input[type=radio]:checked ~ .check::before {
  background: black;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <span>
    <input type="radio" id="f-option" name="selector" checked="checked">
    <label for="f-option"><div>Item 1<br/>Second Line<br/>Third Line</div></label>
    <div class="check"></div>
    </span>
  </li>

  <li>
    <div>
      <input type="radio" id="s-option" name="selector">
      <label for="s-option">
        <div>Second Thing</div>
      </label>

      <div class="check">
        <div class=""></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>

  <li>
    <div>
      <input type="radio" id="t-option" name="selector">
      <label for="t-option">
        <div>Nothing at all
          <br/>Some More stuff here</div>
      </label>

      <div class="check">
        <div class=""></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would change the custom check `div` to `display: inline block`, and then set `vertical-align: middle` on both the `label` and the `div`.

You would have to switch the positions of the `label` and `div` within their containers to have the `div` appear on the left.

Edit: here is an updated pen to demonstrate: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/rrZXab?editors=1100

Comment: Thank you for that!  Can you take a look at this fork, which has a larger list item sizes:  https://codepen.io/anon/pen/YGqmaE?editors=1100 .  It seems the items aren't centered vertically, which is causing the list items to not be equidistant to another.

Comment: If you're setting a fixed height on the `<li>`s, one fix would be to also set the `line-height` to the same value. Then on the `<label>`s, set the `line-height` back to normal: [Pen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/rrZXRO?editors=1100)

Comment: Perfect!  Thank you for your help.